# ajax call append to link

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to append a picture after the link with the same url as the link.
With the AJAX code below i get this outcome:

```
<a href="images/Draadloos.png" data-lightbox="gallerij"></a>
```

Example of what i want:

```
<a href="images/Draadloos.png" data-lightbox="gallerij"><img src="images/Draadloos.png" id="ResizePicture" Alt="Draadloos" /></a>
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/images.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(data).find('images image').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            $('.timeline ').append(
                $('<a />', {
                    href: url,
                    "data-lightbox": "gallerij"

                    }));
            });
        },
    error: function(){
        console.log('Fotos zijn niet ingeladen');
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: Where in the code are you even trying to add an image to the `a` tag?

Comment: Updated the code. It's a lightbox thing http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the image you can call something like this:

```
$('.timeline ').append( 
        $('<a />', { href: "foo.png", html: "<img src=foo.png title=FooImg />"}
));
```

To help you more a demo fiddle or codepen.io would be helpfull. 
For example
 - what is returned from the ajax call - meaning what is inside data?
 - how does the html inside data look like so that find('images image') gives a match

Answer (score 1):

You're doing fine, you just need to append the image element to your a tag:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/images.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(data).find('images image').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            $('.timeline ').append(
                $('<a />', {
                    href: url,
                    "data-lightbox": "gallerij"

                    }).append('<img />', {
                        src: url, 
                        id:"ResizePicture", 
                        alt: url // see my note below on this...
                    }));
            });
        },
    error: function(){
        console.log('Fotos zijn niet ingeladen');
        }
});
```

For the image's `alt` property, you may have another value you can pull out of the XML to fill it with, or you may need to use another method, maybe a regex on the URL, if they're always the same pattern...

Comment: Thank you, it was this kind of solution I was looking for